# Highstocks - Use tickmarkPlacement "between" on datetime Axis (no categories)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there any workaround to have tickMarkPlacement set as "between" on a datetime Axis? I am aware is [not supported by the API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement) but I was hoping to find some sort of hack/plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fudge it with the x axis label's `x` property.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3qtZr/36/

[[update after comments:

if you mean that you want the data points to also line up 'between', then there isn't a good easy way.

My approach would be

1) make sure there is only one data point per axis tick, ideally

2) adjust the x value of the data point to push it to the right in a way that corresponds with the label offset

3) adjust tooltip formatters to correct the date for display

or, 4) just go with categories

However, if you can explain why you want to do this, what effect you're going for, perhaps there's more that can be done.

{{**further updates**:

After playing around a little more, I found another way to fudge the data point placement, though I am unclear whether you need that.

Example here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3qtZr/39/

It uses the `pointPlacement` property.
The catch is that the pointPlacement property doesn't work if there is not a columns series present with as many data points as the line series, it seems.

So this method adds and hidden dummy column series in order to make the `pointPlacement` property affect the line series.

Not elegant, but it beats having to adjust the data values and then re-adjust them in the formatter.

Comment: But that would only affect labels, right? Lines will still be in the same place with regard to the graphic. :S

Comment: what do you mean by 'lines'? Can you put up an example?

Comment: The grid lines appear where the ticks are...that behavior is the same as using 'between' in that regard. See updated answer for more comments

Comment: Well, the example I posted works great. But it's not a datetime axis. I'd like to get exactly that result with datetime axis (not categories).

Comment: the example you posted was just my example, with a datetime axis - not categories - with the gridlines enabled on the x axis. Which, as stated, will fall where the ticks are and are a non-issue. Not sure what else you're looking for here...

Comment: I couldn't check again. I think it doesn't but I'll give you the bounty for the effort. I'll post again after rechecking.

Comment: I am not as much worried about the bounty as I am the fact that I feel the question, as asked, is answered. If it doesn't solve your problem, then there's more to the question that you need to elaborate.

Comment: Here's a fiddle of what I'm trying to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/ozke/30go12jy/4/ But instead of a red line every two columns or in the center of each column, on in between each of them. Which is the default 'between' behavior.

Comment: I'll give this as a valid answer as it provides loads of great tricks and for some purposes it works. For a more specific case I was trying to refer there's a less generic question here, also with a solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066053/highstocks-place-a-line-between-columns-when-using-datetime-axis

Comment: Well...that seems like an entirely different question than what you asked here.

Comment: Hence me creating a new one. Thanks for the help, I think your answer was great for what I was (accidentally) asking for.