# Highstocks - Place a line between columns when using datetime axis

Tags: javascript, datetime, charts, highcharts

Is it possible to place a line between columns when using a datetime axis?

http://jsfiddle.net/ozke/30go12jy/4/

Relevant code:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        gridLineWidth: 1, gridLineColor:'#FF0000', gridZIndex: 4 /* grid line styles */
    },

    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            grouping: false,
            borderWidth: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            pointPadding: 0
        }
    }
```

- I was originally trying to do something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544218/highstocks-use-tickmarkplacement-between-on-datetime-axis-no-categories) but the question evolved a bit to much to a different place. Hence me asking again.

Comment: You can also try to use [minTickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.minTickInterval) and [pointPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPlacement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `plotLines` like this:

```
plotLines: [{
            value: Date.UTC(2014,  1, 15),
            width: 1,
            color: 'red',
            dashStyle: 'dash',
            label: {
                text: 'value',
                align: 'right',
                y: 20,
                x: 0
            }
        },
        {
            value: Date.UTC(2014,  2, 17),
            width: 1,
            color: 'red',
            dashStyle: 'dash',
            label: {
                text: 'value',
                align: 'right',
                y: 20,
                x: 0
            }
        },
        ...
     ]
```

Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/30go12jy/5/)

Comment: That's a nice alternative. Any way of moving the tickmarks too?

Comment: There's a `tickmarkPlacement` property but its only for the categorized axes, and not for `datetime`: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement

Comment: Yeah, I knew that. But it's always 'on'. As you say there's no 'between' unless you use categorized axes.